# How to create a dashboard using Shiny R

Tags: r

I want to create a dashboard using shiny R

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gFkL.jpg)
I had tried it but one type of error showing me i.e. server must be a function

Comment: Hi and welcome Jiban! This question is too broad to be posted here (this website is used for specific, targeted coding questions). The Shiny folks have made a very handy resource center that may help you get started: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/ - and perhaps ore specifically here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/ - good luck!